# Jquery Datatables How to display the results of price in the sorting order?

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm noob with Jquery DataTables. I have a very basic question on how to use the sorting plugins: Have googled a lot on this, but I fail to get proper answers, on how to incorporate them in my code

```
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.4/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
</head>
<body>
<table  id="kiran">
        <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th class="hidden-480">Name</th>
                      <th class="hidden-480">Price</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                  </tbody>
  </table>
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.4/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(function(){
    //$("#kiran").dataTable();

     $('#kiran').dataTable({

         "order": [[ 1, "desc" ]],
          "aaSorting": [[1, 'desc']],



       });


    displayData();
  })

function displayData()
{

  var json = [
    {
        "Name": "ONE",
        "Price": "12"
    },
    {
        "Name": "TWO",
        "Price": "100"
    },
    {
        "Name": "THREE",
        "Price": "42"
    }
]



for(var i=0;i<json.length;i++)
{

var name = json[i].Name;
var price = json[i].Price;

              $('<tr>').append(
              $("<td width='20%''>").text(name),
                $("<td  width='25%'>").text(price)

              ).appendTo('#kiran');


}

}


  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/pg1k5aww/

Could anybody please help how to resolve this ??

Comment: Can't append html into the table itself, either build table first or use API to pass in data  http://jsfiddle.net/pg1k5aww/2/ Alternatively can wire up ajax url and plugin will make ajax call for data

Comment: If you dont mind whats the difference between the fiddle code you provided and mine one ??

Comment: moved the `displayTable()` before the plugin initializing. Your way had no rows until after it was initialized so plugun didn't know you added any after

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like @charlietfl said, you can't directly render data into the table, i made some changes in your fiddle here's my approach. http://jsfiddle.net/5tszcz2q/

i moved the data to a var

```
var data = [
    {
        "Name": "ONE",
        "Price": "12"
    },
    {
        "Name": "TWO",
        "Price": "100"
    },
    {
        "Name": "THREE",
        "Price": "42"
    }
];
```

then i changed you datatable to this configuration

```
"aaData": data, //set the datatables data to the json var previously created
//mapped each column to the respective data it must present
"aoColumns": [
    { "mData": "Name" }, 
    { "mData": "Price" },
 ],
```